# Rearranging multiple stacked dataframes into 1 dataframe using panda in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm completely new to Python and I'm not really sure where to start with this, although Pandas seem like a good option.

I use a scientific instrument which generates the following excel data file.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hTRamdpR_GLRvDmyKeamXWL01s57MmamPwFAE_Q7YN8/edit?usp=sharing

Here is a visual representation of the data structure. 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B36IoWUwP26JNHgtTFNqV3VGZVU/view?usp=sharing

The structure of the data that I get is represented in A (from the image link). I would like to import the excel file into python and then re-order it to give the structure depicted by figure B.

I don't know how to begin to do this so any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I could answer this but really you need to try something first, please take a look at the [IO](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html) section of the docs, also perhaps look at `read_excel` or `read_csv`, in particular I'd look at `nrows` and `skip_rows` params for loading the data into 3 separate dfs and thenc calling `pandas.concat` pass a list of these dfs and pass param `axis=1`. Alternatively load the entire thing into a single df and then slice the df to get the 3 separate dfs and then `concat`

Comment: Thanks. It's hard to know where to start but this will certainly put me on the right track.

Comment: feels like you are handing the stackoverflow community a task. I feel like this question is off-topic because of it. You really should try yourself, then ask specific questions when you get stuck.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, it's my first time on here and I really wasn't sure where to start. I'll post more when I've given EdChums advice a try.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here's my answer based on @EdChum 's suggestions. I imported all the data at once and then I concatenated 2 dataframes as an example. The next stage is to automatically recognise the different dataframes within the excel file instead of having to manually define the slices.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("test data.xlsx",header=None)  #Import all data

df1=df.ix[0:67,:] #Slice first dataframe, give new headings and indices
df1.columns=df1.ix[0,]
df1=df1[1:]
df1=df1.set_index(df1.ix[:,0])

df2=df.ix[69:136,:]  #Slice second dataframe, give new headings and indices
df2.columns=df2.ix[69,]
df2=df2[1:]
df2=df2.set_index(df2.ix[:,0])

frames=[df1,df2] #Define frames as the combination of both databases

result=pd.concat(frames,axis=1) #Concatenate 


result=result.drop('Wavelength', 1) #remove the extra wavelength row

result.to_csv("result.csv") #export result
```